# DTLS implementation in UDP broadcast

Tags: cryptography, dtls

I have a sensor node which broadcast sensor data as UDP packets to a specific port. I have to secure this broadcast. I tried to find out how can I achieve that and found out that DTLS is the answer.
What all do I need to do to implement DTLS? Initially, I thought I do not need certificates, however, I learnt that DTLS is also using handshake to exchange keys. Do I need to create certificates for that ?

Answer (score 2):

DTLS is a version of TLS (which is end-to-end security) used over UDP or other unreliable packet delivery mechanism. DLTS can not be used with broadcasting which is unidirectional.

Now, what is "secure" in your case? Do you need to encrypt the data? But encryption is a concept which is contrary to broadcasting (as the number of recipients grows, security drops exponentially). Signing of data is possible. It is of course possible to encrypt the data for one or multiple recipients (using either symmetric encryption or public-key encryption) but again this is hardly a broadcast and has nothing to do with UDP itself (or other transport).

Comment: Could you please explain more why it does not work with broadcast.

Yes, I have to encrypt data so that only intended recipients could read it. Means, if someone manage to break into the wifi network, he is not able to read or decipher the message.

What is the other options to secure a UDP broadcast if not DTLS?

Comment: @user3648560 You just encrypt the data as you would do with any other transport. Use either low-level symmetric encryption or OpenPGP or PKCS#7 encryption. DTLS won't work because this is a method to build a secure channel, and "broadcast" contradicts to "channel".

Comment: Take paid cable / satellite TV for example, or other DRM-protected material that is broadcast encrypted with a common key that changes time to time. That master key may be disseminated by sending a personal copy of it (encrypted by the recipient's only key, symmetric or asymmetric), whether in broadcast or unicast mode.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov ... and there exist counterfeit cards and devices for decoding this broadcast data. I.e. the security here is not absolute (moreover, it's not even sufficiently reliable).

Comment: @eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp TV counterfeiting is only possible because of engagement and cooperation of legitimate recipients. If no legitimate recipient supplies key data to eavesdropper, then broadcast transmission remains unreadable by unauthorized parties (provided that the protection scheme is not terribly broken). I assume that OP was talking about a controlled environment, where both sender and recipients have no will to disclose sensitive data.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov legitimate recipients in TCP networks can easily lose the secret data due to leaks, and this is the main reason why "broadcast" security doesn't work well.

Comment: @eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp Anyone may lose secret data due to leaks, so what's the difference between broadcast and unicast? Even if one transmits multiple unicast streams (encrypted with personal keys) instead of a single broadcast stream (encrypted with master key), and one recipient leaks his key, — then the stream contents will be available to eavesdropper anyway. In both cases administrator needs to revoke the compromised key and issue a new one instead after fixing the leak.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov the difference is that with growse of potential sources of the leak the chance for the leak grows not in linear manner but exponentially. Now, according to the rules StackOverflow is not a chat system and extended discussions in comments should be avoided.